# Getting CORS error on /connect/token endpoint

Tags: identityserver4

Using IdentityServer4 to secure my Blazor WebAssembly Application. Hosted the Blazor application and Identity server on two servers using IIS. Configured Client-based CORS Configuration for two origins as follows.

```
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new Client[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "Client Id of the Application",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequirePkce = true,
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://subdomain1.domain1.com",
                                       "https://subdomain2.domain2.com"},
                AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "customscope" },
                RedirectUris = { "https://subdomain1.frontend1.com/authentication/login-callback",
                                 "https://subdomain2.frontend2.com/authentication/login-callback"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://subdomain1.frontend1.com/",
                                           "https://subdomain2.frontend2.com/"},
                Enabled = true
            },
        };
```

After successful signing using the username and password, the frontend application trying to get the token using AuthenticationService.js the endpoint is https://identityserver.com/connect/token.

Application1 is working fine which is hosted in server1, whereas application 2 hosted in server 2 failed with CORS error (MissingAllowOriginHeader).

Comment: What does the CORS error in the IdentityServer log fil say?

Comment: You should list your frontend origin on `AllowedCorsOrigins`, based on the code above add  `https://frontend1.com` and `https://frontend2.com`

Comment: Tried as specified. but did not help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of the issue, IIS setting was missed in one of the servers.
We need to set "Load User Profile" to "true" in the application pool of the Identity Server. After making that application works without issues.